# Valve games crashing on startup due to problem with OpenGL/SDL

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, steam

Recently, my games made by valve, and I assume all source games, have been crashing on start up. This isn't affecting any of my other games, which primarily run on Unity3D. It seems to be a problem with how my graphics drivers are currently configured. This problem has persisted even with STEAM_RUNTIME=0, so it isn't a problem with libSDL like many of the workarounds on the internet suggest. I am running Arch Linux using nvidia drivers, version 361.28. Here is the error I get when I try running a valve game:

```
PROBLEM: You appear to have OpenGL 0.0.0, but we need at least 2.0.0!
```

Comment: A) I assume your system is 64-bit? B) Have you tried updating your OpenGL drivers (graphics hardware manufacturer dependent, Google for more info)? and C) have you tried completely removing and reinstalling a game?

Comment: A) Yes B) Yes, all of my drivers are up to date C) Yes. Due to the fact that this affects multiple games that are all connected to one engine, I highly doubt it is a problem with game corruption.

Comment: Also, I am using the proprietary nvidia drivers

Comment: This might help - https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Counter-Strike-Global-Offensive/issues/610

Comment: The workaround detailed in that bug report does in fact fix my issue. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: If it's necessary to include an extract in the answer and not just a link, I shall be happy to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this post](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Counter-Strike-Global-Offensive/issues/610) (on the site for reporting issues in Valve Software)
describes, running `steam` using the following environment variable
works as a workaround to the issue:

```
__GLVND_DISALLOW_PATCHING=1 steam
```

Additionally, this issue was fixed in the Nvidia 364.12 driver update, so updating your driver will also fix this.

Comment: Joe: your answer was flagged for moderator attention. I see that you converted a helpful comment into a link. I'd like to take you up on your offer to include the pertinent parts of that link into your answer here so that Stack Exchange viewers can see the answer here without having to click off to another site (which may or may not remain). Thank you!